# Action Bar in Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse

I try create an action bar to an android application and I have many problems.
Can someone tell me which is the prefered way to create an action bar?

My Code is

```
<menu  >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

But nothing doesnt showes. I want an search icon and a setting icon

Comment: What problems are you having? Can you show us what you have tried to do so far?

Comment: I edit my question with my exist source code

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you are using suppor.v4 (for compaibility) library then use `YourActivity extends FragmentActivity`

otherwise use

```
  ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
```

Comment: I take an error message "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Comment: I type this @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
     ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
 } but does not work

Comment: Now I take this message and the application doesnt star. "Unfortunately My application name has stopped". What can I do. I deleted everything and have only the basic code